# Remove circular dependency of providers in ionic 3 app

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3

I am including a provider in another provider in ionic 3 app. But it is giving me error 'No Provider Found'. I did some research and found that it is due to circular dependency. How can I overcome circular dependency in ionic 3 app?

Comment: Hello! Yeah, of course you can. Start with adding some code to your question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Angular doesn't allow referencing a provider in another one as it may lead to circular dependance injection. The way I solved it was removing declaration of class variable from the constructor and using ***Injector*** from angular core to inject dependancy in timeout using the following code:

So suppose you want to include Provider A in Provider B,

```
import { ProviderA } from '../provider-a/provider-a';

export class ProviderB {
  provider_a:any;
  constructor(public injector: Injector) {
    console.log('Hello ProviderB Provider');
    setTimeout(() => this.provider_a = injector.get(ProviderA));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You CAN reference other providers in a provider, it's just that the other providers CANNOT contain a reference to the provider you are referencing it from. That particular circular reference means that you are including a reference to a provider that ALSO has a reference to the first provider.